# Spine standing out in the middle of the back

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, lower-back, spine

I've started training about 3 months ago. I had neglected my lower back training for a while before starting to train it again.
Now, my body fat percentage is about 10% and my spine is very visible in the middle of my back .
Is this due to the lack of muscle mass in the lower back ? if not,what muscle do I have to train to get rid of that skinny look ?

Note: I do pullups, bodyweight rows and arch ups to train the entire back.

Comment: Training your lower back for growth will be difficult with just your bodyweight, do you have access to any weights or equipment?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr you need no equipment. You just have to decrease leverage which will make the exercise harder.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any exercise you're performing to build muscles in your lower back. The closest bodyweight exercise being performed is the ***pullup;*** however, you'll have to perform wide-grip pull ups and even with that, your upper back and lats will benefit more. I'll go with @LegoStormtroopr and suggest including weights.

Comment: How much pullups *(reps and sets)* do you perform and how often do you train? Also, how long have you been doing the pull ups. Personally, I don't believe bodyweight rows or arch ups can help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it, it's perfectly normal with your low bf percentage - mine used to as well -.

To get rid of it, you just have to start exercising the muscles surrounding (i.e. lower back). If you have access to a gym, I'd recommend doing deadlifts as that will really help, if not try doing supermans (or other bodyweight alternatives), not as good but will still do the trick.